# Java - Rubber alpha function

Tags: java, graphics, alpha, graphics2d

I am currently making a paint program, and am currently implementing a rubber tool (a version which works with alpha colors). The problem is, I can't paint invisible lines via mouseDragged event because they will just go on top of the painting that was there before...

I have considered setRGB on bImg, but it would need to be supported by mouseDragged and also make the thickness of the line variable. Anyone got any ideas?

EDIT: Why down votes?

Comment: I don't know.  I did not downvote you.  Here is +1 just so you don't feel ashamed of trying to learn.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why programming "experts" can't give us rookies a break...

Comment: don't mind downvotes, they are as unimportant as reddit karma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert your image to a [writeableraster](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html) and use getpixel() and setpixel() methods to convert the colors underneath the user's mouse-pointer under certain conditions.

Comment: Thanks, but can I apply thickness to this method?

Comment: This approach would require you to roll your own thickness by applying any color operations to a given number of pixels on either side of the pixel on which the user is clicking.  Might require a bit of coding, but it can work.

Answer (score 2):

The downwote might be related to the fact it is not entirely clear *what* you try to achive, and *how* you already tried it.

I assume that you want to draw lines over your image in `mouseDragged`. These lines should have the effect of a "rubber"/"eraser", removing some of the previously painted pixels, or (when you say that you want to have an alpha value), maybe not *removing* them, but just making them more pale. Changing the pixel values manually with setRGB is not an option, because this rubber-effect should have a certain *thickness*, that you probably selected by setting an `graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness))` before calling `graphics.draw(rubberLine)`.

IF this is all correct, then you will probably have to set an appropriate composite, using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setComposite%28java.awt.Composite%29 . Particularly, you will have to set an AlphaComposite ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html ). You might try out different ones to achieve different "rubber effects", depending on the alpha value that the erased pixels have, and depending on the alpha value that you set for the "rubber color".

EDIT: An example, ... maybe you should describe the problem more clearly

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class SimplePaint
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        PaintPanel paintPanel = new PaintPanel();

        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(
            createControlPanel(paintPanel), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.getContentPane().add(paintPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    static JPanel createControlPanel(final PaintPanel paintPanel)
    {
        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2));
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("Paint");
        final JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 255, 0);
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
            {
                int value = slider.getValue();
                if (value <= 0)
                {
                    label.setText("Paint");
                }
                else
                {
                    label.setText("Rubber alpha "+value);
                }
                paintPanel.setRubber(value);
            }
        });
        controlPanel.add(label);
        controlPanel.add(slider);
        return controlPanel;
    }
}



class PaintPanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener
{
    private BufferedImage image;
    private Point previousPoint = new Point();
    private int rubberAlpha = -1;

    PaintPanel()
    {
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    void setRubber(int alpha)
    {
        this.rubberAlpha = alpha;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        if (image == null)
        {
            image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics imageG = image.getGraphics();
            imageG.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            imageG.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
            imageG.dispose();
        }
        else if (image.getWidth() != w || image.getHeight() != h)
        {
            BufferedImage newImage = 
                new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics imageG = newImage.getGraphics();
            imageG.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            imageG.dispose();
            image = newImage;
        }
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (image == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        if (rubberAlpha > 0)
        {
            g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255,rubberAlpha));
            Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(previousPoint, e.getPoint());
            g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20, 
                BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
            g.draw(line);
        }
        else
        {
            g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0,255));
            Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(previousPoint, e.getPoint());
            g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20, 
                BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
            g.draw(line);
        }

        g.dispose();
        repaint();

        previousPoint = e.getPoint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        previousPoint = e.getPoint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried aComposite, did not work; am currently testing the raster method. Thansk for the help though.

Comment: That code is incorrect, as you cannot use a line with alpha value to draw over an opaque one. Anyway, the problem has been solved.

Comment: Obviously, you can. Or what do you think is done in the above code?